# Place the result of a join in a sub-object rather than "flat" in the result

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table `people`, a table `departments` and a table `addresses`.
I am wondering if there is a way **in mySql** to have some of the results as JSON rather than added rows or tables.

For this example:

```
people:
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name         | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| departmentId | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

addresses
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| personId    | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fullAddress | varchar(125) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

departments;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Note: to create tables, run:

```
create table people ( id INT(11), name varchar(50), departmentId INT(11));
create table departments ( id INT(11), name varchar(50));
create table addresses ( id INT(11), personId INT(11), fullAddress varchar(125));
```

So a person can be linked to one specific department, but can have several addresses.

```
insert into departments values (0, 'sales');
insert into departments values (1, 'dev');

insert into people values (0, 'Chiara', 0);
insert into people values (1, 'Geoff', 0);
insert into people values (2, 'Tony', 1);
insert into people values (3, 'Raphael', 1);

insert into addresses values (0, 0, 'Street 0');
insert into addresses values (1, 0, 'Street 1');
insert into addresses values (2, 1, 'Street 2');
insert into addresses values (3, 1, 'Street 3');
insert into addresses values (4, 2, 'Street 4');
insert into addresses values (5, 2, 'Street 5');
insert into addresses values (6, 2, 'Street 6');
insert into addresses values (7, 2, 'Street 7');
insert into addresses values (8, 3, 'Street 8');
insert into addresses values (9, 3, 'Street 9');
```

**QUESTION 1: JOIN 1:n as array rather than as multiple results**

I can easily do a select and get all records in `people`:

```
select * from people left join addresses on people.id = addresses.personId where people.id = 2;
```

The result of this is:

```
+------+------+--------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id   | name | departmentId | id   | personId | fullAddress |
+------+------+--------------+------+----------+-------------+
|    2 | Tony |            1 |    7 |        2 | Street 7    |
|    2 | Tony |            1 |    6 |        2 | Street 6    |
|    2 | Tony |            1 |    5 |        2 | Street 5    |
|    2 | Tony |            1 |    4 |        2 | Street 4    |
+------+------+--------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Is there an easy, straightforward way to have only ONE record as result (the contact ID 2) and have the addresses in an ARRAY (or, a JSON containing the addresses) instead?

**QUESTION 2: JOIN 1:1 as a sub-object rather than adding columns**

I can easily get the department information by using joins:

```
select * from people left join departments on departments.id = people.departmentId where people.id = 2 ;
```

Result:

```
+------+------+--------------+------+------+
| id   | name | departmentId | id   | name |
+------+------+--------------+------+------+
|    2 | Tony |            1 |    1 | dev  |
+------+------+--------------+------+------+
```

However, what if I wanted a result like this instead:

```
+------+------+--------------+----------------------+
| id   | name | departmentId | departmentIdRecord   |
+------+------+--------------+----------------------+
|    2 | Tony |            1 | { id: 1, name: "dev"}|
+------+------+--------------+----------------------+
```

Basically having the departmentIdRecord column as a JSON containing the department record.

Is this even possible with MySql?

Comment: Have you tried using the `JSON_OBJECT()` function to create JSON?

Comment: It seems like you need to read up on the JSON functions in MySQL. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html

Comment: Use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` for question 1, and `JSON_OBJECT()` for question 2.